# WeatherCan app won’t launch on iPad mini 2

Tags: ipad, applications

WeatherCan app from Environment Canada won’t launch on iPad mini 2 (Wi-Fi), model identifier iPad4.4. It used to work just fine and now won’t open. The splashscreen appears and then it closes down. There are no error messages. I have tried re-installing it and the iOS. No joy. Any idea what is happening? Thanks.

Comment: Version of iPadOS? I can’t download the app myself because I’m not in Canada. Are you in Canada?

Comment: Latest version of iOS 12. Yes, in Canada.

Comment: Perhaps it will now not run on your iPad Mini and iOS 12? I can find no specs for the app as I cannot view it in the App Store. You need to write the developer of the app to find out.

Comment: K, thanks for looking. I suspect that the Mini is just too old. It must only be available in the Canadian App Store. Yay! iPad shopping here I go.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the iPad Mini 2 is just too 'old' a device to run this version of the app. Absent definitive confirmation from the developer, this is just supposition.